# Creating daily to monthly trigger dependency in ADFv2

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have a tumbling window trigger **trg-Daily** that has a start date boundary at 12:00AM and it executes once every 24 hours (frequency is **Hour** and interval is **24**). So basically it executes a daily job. Now I a pipeline that I want to execute once a month -- so basically I want to create another tumbling window trigger **trg-Monthly** that will depend on the daily trigger **trg-Daily** in such a way that it should execute when all the days in a given month are processed. How to define this? Specifically I would like to know what should be the following values of the trigger **trg-Monthly** to make it happen?

1. frequency
2. interval
3. window Size (for dependsOn section)
4. offset ( for dependsOn section)

This used to happen easily out of the box in ADFv1 , not sure how to implement that in ADFv2.

Comment: Hi,does my answer helps you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that monthly trigger is not supported in ADF v2 so far(never get any response from official team yet now) based on this [feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/270578-data-factory/suggestions/33869644-adfv2-tumbling-window-trigger-month-and-year-fre).

Just provide a workaround here,using [Recurrence Schedule trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-native-recurrence) in Logic App service which supports monthly trigger:

[image]

Then use ADF connector action to trigger your specific pipeline:

[image]